# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Error

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io, exception, java.util.scanner

I am using Eclipse to compile and run my java codes.

**Here is Error I am getting.**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at helloworld.main(helloworld.java:9)
```

**Here is my Code**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class helloworld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner KB = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        while (KB.hasNext()) {
            String line = KB.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    }
}
```

**File.txt**
I have created file.txt in same folder in my project.

Comment: Is your file directly under your project folder?

Comment: it is under SCR, I put one under bin as well, because scr didn't work.

Comment: Try printing `new File("file.txt").exists()` Is it yielding `true`? if not, try printing `new File("file.txt").getAbsoluteFile()` Is it what you expected?

Comment: It is looking for the file file.txt in the same directory you are executing this from.  If that is from a IDE, check what the working directory is set to.

Comment: Try putting it under the same folder as your .class files.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your file should directly be under the project folder, and not inside any other sub-folder.

So, if your project folder is `MyProject`, it's folder structure(not complete though) should be like: -

```
MyProject +- src +
          |      |
          |      +-- Your source file
          +- file.txt
```

It should not be `under src` folder.

---

Or, you can give the following path relative to the project folder to search for file in the `src folder`: -

```
new File("src/file.txt");
```

Comment: Ah brilliant. Didn't guess.

Comment: This answer saved me a day's time @Rohit :-)

Answer (score 6):

Try passing the complete path to the file, say:

```
new File("/usr/home/mogli/file.txt")
```

Or if you're in windows:

```
new File("C:/Users/mogli/docs/file.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

Either follow @rohit Jains approach or give the **absolute path** for your **file** like:

```
 Scanner KB = new Scanner(new File("C:/JsfProjects/Project/file1.txt"));
            while (KB.hasNext()) {
                String line = KB.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
```

Comment: +1 Consider using the forward-slash `/` instead of the backward-slash \.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows try giving real path like this

```
"C:\\Users\\mogli\\docs\\file.txt"
```

It worked for me.