# Calling a method to read from a text file with BufferedReader

Tags: bufferedreader, java-io

I searched around for this but I could not find a soultion.

Sorry about my bad description. Im not very good at this.

I have a UI class
Its calling a "lotto" class.

That lotto classes constructor is called a method named readData()
readData is reading from a file using BufferedReader

Im not getting an error message but its just not reading.
It gets stuck at BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader... and goes to the catch thing.

If its a file not found problem how would i make it track where my file is. Im using eclipse and the program is stored on my usb. I need to hand it in to my teacher so i cant just put a location in. Is there code that tracks where my program is then takes the file from that folder?

Here is the code being used.

import java.io.*;

```
//contructor

public Lotto()
{
    try
    {
        readData();
        nc = new NumberChecker();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("There was a problem");
    }
}

private void readData() throws IOException
{
    //this method reads winning tickets date and pot from a file

    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("data.txt"));


    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("in "+i);
        winningNums[i] = file.readLine();
        winningDates[i] = file.readLine();
        weeksMoney[i] = Integer.parseInt(file.readLine());
        System.out.println("out "+i);
    }

    file.close();

}
```

Comment: what is the exception u get?

Answer (score 0):

if you get an error in this line of code

```
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("data.txt"));
```

Then it is probably a [FileNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)

Make sure that the data.txt file is in the same folder as your compiled .class file and not the .java source.

It would be best to use a proper root to your file ex. c:\my\path\data.txt

And don't forget the \

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the BufferedReader in a try catch and look for a file not found exception as well as IO exception. Also try putting in the fully qualified path name with double backslashes.

```
BufferedReader file;
    try {
        file = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("C:\\filepath\\data.txt"));

         for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("in "+i);
                winningNums[i] = file.readLine();
                winningDates[i] = file.readLine();
                weeksMoney[i] = Integer.parseInt(file.readLine());
                System.out.println("out "+i);
            }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: If its a file not found problem how would i make it track where my file is. Im using eclipse and the program is stored on my usb. I need to hand it in to my teacher so i cant just put a location in. Is there code that tracks where my program is then takes the file from that folder?

Normally what i put works but it seems like it is a file not found problem

Comment: This link might help. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592325/exception-in-thread-main-java-io-filenotfoundexception-error). you have to make sure that your file is directly under your project folder.