# Scanner lists error

Tags: java, file

**Code**

```js
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Fileread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("List.txt");
        String country="india";
        int count=countWord(country,file);

        System.out.println("The number of students from"+country+" is "+count);

    }
    public static int countWord(String word, File file) {
        int count = 0;
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextToken = scanner.next();
            if (nextToken.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
            count++;
        }
        return count;
        }

}
```

**Error**:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: List.txt`
>   `(The system cannot find the file specified)   at`
>   `java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)   at`
>   `java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)    at`
>   `java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)  at`
>   `random.Fileread.countWord(Fileread.java:25)   at`
>   `random.Fileread.main(Fileread.java:17)`

Comment: Please check
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592325/exception-in-thread-main-java-io-filenotfoundexception-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.txt` is a relative path, so it depends on what your application thinks as "current directory."

To be able to fix errors like this, always use absolute paths:

```
File file = new File("List.txt").getAbsoluteFile();
```

That will tell where exactly the system looked for the file.

The next step is then fixing the problem. The fix depends on many factors, and there is no simple solution.