# Sphinx4 dictionary file not found

Tags: java, dictionary, filenotfoundexception, sphinx4

I am using Sphinx4 for custome home automatization software and I am stuck on using my custom dict file, for some reason it cant find the file even though I am sure I am using the correct path. 
This is my code :

```
package pccomone;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer;

public class Main {

private static final String BODICPATH = "PCCom/src/resource/bodict.dict";

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
    configuration.setDictionaryPath(BODICPATH);
    //configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict"); use only for large commands!!!!!!!!!
    configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");

    LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

    recognizer.startRecognition(true);

    SpeechResult result;

    while((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null){
        String command = result.getHypothesis();
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
            recognizer.stopRecognition();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println(command);
    }
}
```

}

I didn't come far since I can't get it to use my custom dict file and the included dict file is way to large for the software to work fast and accurate.

This is the Error,

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Allocation of
>   search manager resources failed
>         at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.allocate(WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:247)
>         at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.AbstractDecoder.allocate(AbstractDecoder.java:103)
>         at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.allocate(Recognizer.java:164)
>         at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer.startRecognition(LiveSpeechRecognizer.java:47)
>         at pccomone.Main.main(Main.java:26)
>       Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: PCCom\src\resource\bodict.dict (The system cannot find the path
>   specified)
>         at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>         at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>         at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
>         at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.dictionary.TextDictionary.allocate(TextDictionary.java:180)
>         at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.LexTreeLinguist.allocate(LexTreeLinguist.java:332)
>         at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.allocate(WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:243)
>         ... 4 more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592325/exception-in-thread-main-java-io-filenotfoundexception-error)

Comment: Simply point a proper path. If you are not sure about relative path, point an absolute path.